# Checking if a graph is bipartite in a DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, runtime, time-complexity

I wonder what will be the complexity of this algorithm of mine and why, used to check whether a graph (given in the form of neighbors list) is bipartite or not using DFS.

The algorithm works as following:

- We will use edges classification, and look for back edges.
- If we found one, it means there is a circle in the graph.
- We will now check whether the cycle is odd cycle or not, using the the pi attribute added to each vertex, counting the number of edges participating in the cycle.
- If the cycle is an odd one, return false. Else, continue the process.

Initially I thought the complexity will be O(|V| + |E|) as |V| stands for the number of vertices in the graph, and |E| stands for the number of edges in the graph, but I am afraid it might take O(|V| + |E|^2), and I wonder which option is correct and why (it may not be any of the above as well). Amortized or expected run times may also be different, and I wonder how can I check them as well.

***pseudo code***

```
DFS(G=(V,E))
// π[u] – Parent of u in the DFS tree 
1 for each vertex u ∈ V {
2 color[u] ← WHITE
3 π[u]← NULL
4 time ← 0}
5 for each vertex u ∈ V {
6 if color[u] = WHITE
7 DFS-VISIT(u)}
```

and for the DFS-Visit:

```
DFS-Visit(u)
// white vertex u has just been discovered
1 color[u] ← GRAY
2 time ← time+1
3 d[u] ← time
4 for each v ∈ Adj[u] { // going over all edges {u, v}
5 if color[v] = WHITE {
6 π[v] ← u
7 DFS-VISIT(v) }
8 else if color[v] = GRAY // there is a cycle in the graph 
9 CheckIfOddCycle (u, v); 
10 color[u] ← BLACK
// change the color of vertex u to black as we finished going over it
11 f[u] ← time ← time+1
```

and as for deciding what type of cycle is it:

```
CheckIfOddCycle(u, v)
1 int count  ← 1; 
2 vertex p = u; 
3 while (p! = v) {
4 p ← π[p]  
5 count++ }
6 if count is an odd number {
7 S.O.P (“The graph is not bipartite!”); 
8 stop the search, as the result is now concluded!
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can check a back-edge for oddness in constant time, which makes this algorithm take O(|V|+|E|) time

Comment: Also: this algorithm works, but your description of it doesn't really indicate that you know why it works.

Comment: It's a question related to a course in the university, but not an homework question or a question for submission in any way but rather a question of my own about a concept I have been thinking of.

Comment: @MattTimmermans the question is, how can I assure that the search takes constant time? I mean, in the worst case, isn't it a possible scenario to go over all the edges of the graph over and over again each time we count the edges participating in the cycle, and do it |E| times? that's what I am not sure of. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To determine whether or not a graph is bipartite, do a DFS or BFS that covers all the edges in the entire graph, and:

- When you start on a new vertex that is disconnected from all previous vertices, color it blue;
- When you discover a new vertex connected to a blue vertex, color it red;
- When you discover a new vertex connected to a red vertex, color it blue;
- When you find an edge to a previously discovered vertex, return FALSE if it connects blue to blue or red to red.
- If you make it through the entire graph, return TRUE.

This algorithm takes very little work on top of the BFS or DFS, and is therefore O(|V|+|E|).

This algorithm is also essentially the *same* as the algorithm in your question.  When we discover a back-edge with the same color on both sides, it means that the cycle(s) we just discovered are of odd length.

But really this algorithm has nothing to do with cycles.  A graph can have a lot more cycles than it has vertices or edges, and a DFS or BFS will not necessarily find them all, so it wouldn't be accurate to say that we are searching for odd cycles.

Instead we are just trying to make a bipartite partition and returning whether or not it's possible to do so.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I know this algorithm quite well, but I know from graph theory that a graph is 2 colored if and only if it has no odd cycles. Therefore, I concluded that the algorithm I mentioned in my question has to work, but I wondered what will be the complexity of it: O(|V|+|E|) as the known algorithm you presented in your comment, or maybe O(|V|*|E|) or O(|V|+|E|^2), since an edge can take place in more than one cycle, as you mentioned in your comment. How can I decide?

Comment: @Ron K, your algorithm doesn't find ALL cycles, so how does it prove that a graph is bipartite?

Comment: Why won't it find all the cycles? Using edges classification in DFS I should find any cycles in the graph, as can be seen here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rCj3xbTW - added the pseudo code of my algorithm here. It might not be perfect, but it presents the general idea of my algorithm and how it should work.

Comment: @Ron.K when you find an edge that's in a cycle, it can actually be in *many* cycles, but you will only check one of them.

Comment: It does work. The way you wrote it takes O(|V|+|E|^2) time.  More accurately O(|V|(1+|E|)) time.  If you optimize CheckIfOddCycle by remembering the depth of each vertex, then you end up with my algorithm, which takes O(|V|+|E|) time.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit why? that's what I am not sure I have figured out. How would it be possible to do the process for each and every vertex in the graph? it seems a little bit odd to me that we won't visit each edge a constant number of times

Comment: You should do some experiments.  Try a complete graph with 4 vertices in each partition.  How many cycles does your algorithm check?  How many cycles are there? How many edge visits does CheckIfOddCycle do?

Comment: From what I see there shouldn't be any problem with that an edge can take place in more than one cycle and in each check I went over it constant number of times. The problem is, can it be proved?
 or the worst case still stands on O(|V|(1+|E|)) in your opinion. Moreover, can you please explain about the upgrade to CheckIfOddCycle you have suggested? Thanks a lot for all the help! for example, I don't see any situation more complicated than http://i.imgur.com/vKCyG1q.png

Comment: I mean, an edge can "touch" only 2 regions right? Therefore, why can't we bound the number of times an edge can be visited - twice at most, one per each circle?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260946774/figure/fig15/AS:324917263388690@1454477720481/Complete-bipartite-graph-K34.png